# Selecting column by separator in text editor

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext, text-editor

How I can select a column separated by a delimiter using a text editor( like `notepad++` , `sublime` etc etc).

For example this is my text:

```
1053-57-1-5435345-423
3-4-2-6-2
3433434-3-5-2-5
```

and let's say I want to select the 4th column

```
5435345
6
2
```

I know that notepad++ or sublime are used for complex operations so I thought that's it could be possible to do that.

note: as you can see , selecting column by the drag method won't work because the length of each row is not constant.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With notepad++**

Use replace with regex:

Type Ctrl-H

Find what: `^(?:[^-]+-){3}([^-]+).*$`
Replace with: `$1`

Make sure that `Regular expression` is checked.
Click on `Replace All`.

Comment: @user2776193:Sorry, I've forgotten the quantifier `+` in `(?:[^-]+-)`. See my edit.